# That or which? Which pronoun to use for things?

Tags: word-choice, difference, pronouns, that-vs-which

For example:

That book **which** is on the table is mine.
That book **that** is on the table is my book.

Are there any rules when to choose **that** or **which**?

Comment: MR.eee, welcome to ELL!  I hope you'll find the answer to your question on the question linked at the top of this page, and continue to stay here at ELL and ask more questions!